# C# Error: interface members cannot have definition

Tags: c#, interface, member

I am new to C#, and I do not understand why I can not do this.
Can someone provide a link or example that will achieve the same result.

```
public interface IEffectEditorControl
{
    object[] EffectParameterValues
    {
        get;
        set { isDirty = true; }
    }
    bool isDirty { get; set; }
    IEffect TargetEffect { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should read up on what interfaces are designed for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx would be a good starting point - or a decent book. Stack Overflow is good for specific issues, but is *not* a good way of learning a language to start with.

Comment: Rob Miles C# Yellow Book would be a good place to start: http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Your compiler is right, `interface` members indeed cannot have a definition.

An [`interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) defines a *contract* for a class, i.e. a list of properties and methods which must be implemented by a class. It cannot include actual code, like the `isDirty = true;` statement in your example.

In other words, you should change it into:

```
// this only lists all the members which a class must implement,
// if it wants to implement the interface and pass compilation 
public interface IEffectEditorControl
{
    object[] EffectParameterValues { get; set; }  // <-- removed the statement
    bool IsDirty { get; set; }
    IEffect TargetEffect { get; set; }
}
```

And then have a certain `class` *implement* the interface by providing the necessary code:

```
// whichever code accepts the interface IEffectEditorControl,
// can now accept this concrete implementation (and you can have 
// multiple classes implementing the same interface)
public class EffectEditorControl : IEffectEditorControl
{
    private object[] _effectParameterValues; 
    public object[] EffectParameterValues
    {
        get
        { 
            return _effectParameterValues;
        }
        set
        { 
            _effectParameterValues = value;
            IsDirty = true;
        }
    }

    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }
    public IEffect TargetEffect { get; set; }
}
```

Also, note the difference between `EffectParameterValues`, which is a full-blown property with a backing field (`_effectParameterValues`), and `IsDirty`/`TargetEffect`, which are [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) with a private anonymous backing field. Setting the `EffectParameterValues` to a value will execute the whole setter block, modifying both the backing field and the `IsDirty` property.

When you need your get/set accessors do to more than just assign a single value (like setting `IsDirty` in this example), you need to add the actual backing field and do the entire logic yourself. Otherwise, you can use the simpler variant.

#### Extension methods can sometimes perform the same task.

Alternatively, if you really have a common functionality for an interface, you can use an extension method. Note that this still doesn't add actual code to an interface, but essentially creates static methods which can conveniently be invoked on each class implementing that interface.

In this case, you can leave the class "dumb" and make it auto-implement everything:

```
// setting the EffectParameterValues directly won't
// set the IsDirty flag in this case
public class EffectEditorControl : IEffectEditorControl
{
    public object[] EffectParameterValues { get; set; }
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }
    public IEffect TargetEffect { get; set; }
}
```

...then add an extension method to the interface:

```
public static class IEffectEditorControlExtension
{
    public static void SetParametersAndMarkAsDirty
        (this IEffectEditorControl obj, object[] value)
    {
        obj.EffectParameterValues = value;
        obj.IsDirty = true;
    }
}
```

...and then remember to assign parameters through that method later:

```
// this will call the static method above
editor.SetParametersAndMarkAsDirty(parameters);
```

This is most likely not the best use case for extension methods (nothing prevents you from setting `EffectParameterValues` directly and messing the whole thing), but I've added it for completeness sake.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are just "rules" that other classes should implement, in order to work in the desired way.

That's why they don't have an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the title of your question.  An interface in C# is just that an interface.  You can only provide method and property declarations you cannot provide any implementations.

Also in your example besides being an interface you are also using an auto property for get and providing an implementation for set.  This is not allowed.  You either need to implement both get and set or use auto properties for both.

If you wish to have a mixture of declarations and implementations use an abstract class instead of an interface.